# Calculate score in a pyramid score system

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to calculate gamescores for a bunch over users and I haven't really got it yet. It is a pyramid game where you can invite people, and the people you invite is placed beneth you in the relations tree.

So if i invite X and X invites Y i get kickback from both of them. Let's say 10%^steps...

So from X i get 10% of his score and 1% from Y, and X get 10% from Y.

So to calculate this i was thinking that each "player" had a function that calculated his total score. This function had to be recursive and "know" how far in the tree it was so that it would kick back the right values.

```
def get_score(player):
    if children:
        score = player.points
        for child in children:
            score += child.points*math.pow(.1, get_ancestors(child))
            score += get_score(child)
        return score
    else:
        return player.points
```

But this doesnt work proper, it gives what i believe is the right values in some levels but not in others. So  think my function is broken. Anybody got an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I hope you are not going to go all Madoff :)

Comment: No sorry, it's actually for an ARG game with a money price and no costs for the player so no worries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt these two lines

```
score += child.points*math.pow(.1, get_ancestors(child))
score += get_score(child)
```

this is a simple recursive structure so  i think something like below will suffice

```
score += get_score(child)*.1
```

and recursive beauty will take care of itself

you also do not need 'if children:' check
so does it help

```
def get_score(player):
    score = player.points
    for child in children:
        score += get_score(child)*.1
    return score
```

Comment: You're so absolutely correct, doh how can i have missed this, I definitly need some recursive practice. Thanks alot.

Comment: recursion is basically so simple that it trips our complex minds

Answer (score 0):

This can have very different implementations, depending on the way the score must be calculating :

- Do you need to propagate the result of each gain, in real time ? In that case , you start from the bottom of the pyramid and give the feedback until the top.
- Can you afford the result to be calculated at the end of the game for everybody ? In that cas you can just set a method on each player and only call the one at the top.

**E.G for the second option**

You used a functional approach. While this is valid, I am more into OO so I'll go this way :

```
class Player(object) :

    def __init__(self) :
        self.score = 0;
        self.children = []

    def updateScore(self) :
        self.score = self.score + sum(((children.score * 10 / 100) for children in self.children))


class Pyramid(object) :

    def __init__(self) :
        self.top_child = Player()

    def updateScore(self, player = None) :

      if player == None :
          player = self.top_child

      for child in player.children :
           self.updateScore(child)
           child.updateScore()
```

You may want to use itertools to make it less CPU and memory intensive.